# The "consonant" in the Panel

Tags: c#, wpf, panel

I'm passing time by "playing" with `System.Windows.Controls.Panel`s. I stumbled over the `_zConsonant`-Field. I just cannot figure out why this field has such a name... Can someone explain how this whole "Z-Index" System works?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not a property; that's a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controls pile on top of each other.  Every time you add a component in a container it gets a z-index to determine its order (which controls it is "on top" of and which are below).

Visual editing with things like "Bring To Front..." set the Z-index of the selected control to be the frontmost, for example.  It determines the order in which the components are drawn (so that things "in front" draw over things "behind").

In XAML the z-index is determined by the ordering of the declarations.  Things nearer the bottom of the file (declared later) have a higher z-index (are nearer to the front).

see : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Clear and concise humanized answer, +1

Answer (score 2):

Well you can read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for starters.

Then look at the documentation for [Canvas.ZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.zindex%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) as it may paint a better picture.

TLDR; ZIndex is used to specify in what "order" the control will show up over other controls with a specific ZIndex.

Bonus: I found a "hidden" control stacking trick.  That is, in XAML, the control listed last will show up over another control.  For instance that this:

```
<Grid>
    <local:MyLowerControl DataContext="{Binding}"
                          Visibility="{Binding IsPopupNotVisible, Converter={StaticResource convertVisibility}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    <local:MyOverControl HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         x:Name="popup"
                         DataContext="{Binding}"
                         Visibility="{Binding IsPopupVisible, Converter={StaticResource convertVisibility}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
```

If both Visibilities are set to Visible, the last listed control will show up over any controls defined before it.  In this case, `MyOverControl` will show up on top of `MyLowerControl`